# Difference beween "oscillate", "vibrate", "shake", "quake", "resonate"?

Tags: terminology, technical

[Background]

I am not a native English speaker. I am learning electronics and comes to some circuit that can "oscillate".

[Question]

I want to know the difference beween "oscillate", "vibrate", "shake", "quake" and "resonate".

And why a device is named "oscilloscope" rather than "shakescope" or "vibratescope"?

Comment: What research have you done (e.g. dictionaries, online searches, etc.) & what **specific** questions do you have after that research?  Voting to close for following reason: "Please include the research you've done, or consider if your question suits our English Language Learners site better. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic. "

Comment: It's called an oscilloscope because *oscillation* is cyclical. None of the other words connote that. For he balance of your question, please consult a dictionary and tell us what you found for differences. The rules of the site prohibit us from answering you until you do that.

Comment: With regard to electronics, only *oscillate* applies (unless you have a loudspeaker or other electro-mechanical device in the circuit).  (Well, OK, maybe *resonate* applies a little bit, but only if you have an L-C circuit or some such.)

Comment: I think it should be better to delay for accepting the answer ,because it discourages others for participating for most perfect answer.

Comment: @Rwy5 Thanks for the reminding. I can re-mark the answer if a better answer shows up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An oscillation defines a regular, periodic sort of motion. See: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/oscillation In the case of oscilloscopes, you're monitoring voltage or current as a function of time, which is displayed a result of a well understood mathematical model (e.g. the equation modelling the current through an inductor, L = di/dt).

Vibrate and shake don't imply any periodic or regular nature about the motion - in fact, things are usually quite erratic when they shake or vibrate about.

Quakes usually refer to a large scale shaking, usually of the earth.

[**Resonation**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/resonate) is something entirely different again.

> to continue to produce a loud, clear, deep sound for a long time

Your acoustic guitar will resonate if you smack it on the body with your hand, for instance.

Comment: Regardless of whether you think the question is off topic, downvoting a reasonable answer that may actually help someone is poor form in my opinion. If the question is closed and my answer is deleted, there's no harm. If it remains open, there is also no harm.

Comment: Thanks, I did a few search and can find the definition of each word. But I am just not so sure about my own comparison of them. Your answer helped me out.

Comment: Resonance can apply to an L-C circuit.

Comment: Yes, you're quite right. In fact, it resonates in much the same way.